# google cloud ssh inconsistent

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created 4 instances in two separate instance groups based on two vm templates.

Initially I was using the "SSH" button within google cloud console, and I noticed about 40% of the time would it actually work. I would often have to stop/restart the machines in order for the SSH to work. After a day or so later, the SSH button stops working. I figured this was just silly bug, and having actual SSH keys and logging in via normal SSH would work fine.

Well today I configured normal ssh keys, and I was getting the following on 3 of 4 instances:

> Permission denied (publickey).

I logged into the cloud console and clicked the ssh button on all 4 instances and low and behold only 1 / 4 works.

So my question is... why am I having to keep rebooting instances just to keep my ssh working. I have never had this problem on any other cloud server before.

Note: I created a base ubuntu from their available images, and built a generic server, then used that as the base template and forked it to create the other 2 instance group templates.

I am thinking that the ssh daemon might be crashing, but how the heck can I tell, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There are several ways to [troubleshoot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) SSH issues. Have you tried to debug the issue in the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#debug_the_issue_in_the_serial_console)? In the instance serial console, you might find useful logs connected with this issue. I hope this helps you.

Comment: The silence indicated that it was just me. As such, I rebuilt my servers from a different image, and now the ssh daemon is reliable.

Comment: I would recommend you to post your solution as an answer in this discussion so that other community members could take advantage of it for similar concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the silence from the community as an indicator that the problem was only affecting myself. It turns out the stock image I had chosen to start as a base template had a buggy SSH daemon. It was a fairly quick process to rebuild my templates off of a different stock image, and since then I have had no problems connecting to my machines via ssh.

Comment: I got the same problem, what do you mean by stock image?

Comment: When you create an instance, it uses an instance template/image that someone else put together. In my case, the one I had used was buggy. I deleted the server instance, and started a new one created by someone else. This solved my problem.